# Do controller methods need to be async/await in NestJS when using prisma?

Tags: async-await, nestjs, prisma

In general I understand async/await but in this instance it confuses me what the best practise is. Im not sure whether you are supposed to make the controller methods async/await just like the service that it calls.

So this is my current code for creating a country in the database:

**In country.controller.ts**

```
@Post()
  async createCountry(@Body() createCountryDto: CreateCountryDto,): Promise<Country> {
    return await this.countryService.createCountry(createCountryDto);
  }
```

**In country.service.ts**

```
async createCountry(createCountrynDto: CreateCountryDto): Promise<Country> {
    try {
      const country: Country = await this.prisma.country.create({
        data: {
          name: createCountrynDto.name,
        },
      });

      return country;
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof PrismaClientKnownRequestError) {
        if (error.code === 'P2002') {
          throw new ConflictException('County name must be unique');
        }
      }
      throw error;
    }
  }
```

If I call async/await in createCountry in my country.service.ts file do i have to also make my controller function async and await the result as well? I get no complaints about needing async await in the controller but is it better with it or without and why?

The NestJs docs for the example code for prisma don't await the result in the controller but they make the function async nonetheless. Most tutorials ignore this part and don't even make the controller function async.

Also another option I see a lot that people use in tutorials is to implement the service createCountry like this:

```
async createCountry(createCountrynDto: CreateCountryDto) {
      return this.prisma.country.create({
        data: {
          name: createCountrynDto.name,
        },
      });
}
```

Wouldn't this make it so you can't catch the Prisma unique error constraint since the Promise is not awaited? Maybe this is usefull for handling the errors in the controller?

Answer (score 0):

It's considered a best practice to mark the controller method as `async` and await the result from the service method. You don't need to explicitly `await` the promise since returning it from an async function will automatically resolve the promise. You are right, you can catch the Prisma unique error constraint but, remember that handling Prisma-specific errors in the controller can cause coupling between the controller and the Prisma library. If you want to keep the controller generic and independent, it's often better to handle those errors in the service layer

I should add that if you do decide to use `async/await` in the `createCountry` method of your `country.service.ts`. Then yes, it's recommended that you have to use it in the contoller as well

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for the tip about decoupling Prisma library from the controller. I have also seen some desputes about where error handling should be done i.e in the service or in the controller, what are your thoughts on this?. In this case I am considering moving the prisma exception handling in a exception filter